# Why is my method adding an extra blank line at the end?

Tags: c#

I use the below method to remove all blank lines from a file but it is for some reason adding an extra line at the end of the document?

```
var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
try
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tempFileName))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    File.Copy(tempFileName, file, true);
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(tempFileName);
}
```

How do I fix this?

Also can the code be made shorter?

Comment: Because you have `WriteLine` which add new line char at the end...

Comment: @Johnny how do I fix it?

Comment: side note: Use File.Move instead of File.Copy., then you do not need to delete.

Comment: For first (non-empty) line, use `streamWriter.Write(...)`, for all the rest use `streamWriter.Write(Environment.NewLine + line)` (or `streamWriter.WriteLine();streamWriter.Write(line)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamWriter.WriteLine()` will always append a new line (a carriage return, line feed pair) after the string, so I assume that's what you're referring to. To me, it's normal and best to have the last line followed by a new line. But if you don't want it, don't write one.

As far as the length of your code, it looks about right to me. If it seems to detract from your program logic, just move it into its own method.

For efficiency, you might try deleting the original file and then renaming the temporary file. That would be more efficient than copying the entire file.

```
var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
try
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tempFileName))
    {
        string line;
        bool isFirstLine = true;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                if (!isFirstLine)
                    streamWrite.WriteLine();
                streamWriter.Write(line);
                isFirstLine = false;
            }
        }
    }
    File.Delete(file);
    File.Move(tempFileName, file);
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(tempFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Also can the code be made shorter?

A more efficient solution to the other answer:

```
File.WriteAllLines(file, File.ReadLines("some/path").Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)));
```

`File.ReadLines()` is more efficient than `File.ReadAllLines()` because it allows you to query the `IEnumerable<string>` without reading it all into memory first.

We then take the resulting `IEnumerable<string>` from our `Where()` method and pass it to an overload of [`File.WriteAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an `IEnumerable<string>` as its second parameter.

Comment: @RandRandom: Framework 4 added an IEnumerable overload. However, this version won't work when writing to the same file due to lazy evaluation.

Comment: @maccettura isn't there a streamreader alternative...`WriteAllLines` still loads the entire file into memory

Comment: @Bumba [`WriteAllLines()` uses a StreamWriter under the hood](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,8a8ede9e1ec4fece), it just makes your code a whole lot simpler

Comment: That's good but it still will output line break on the final line, which, as I understand, OP does not want.

Comment: @maccettura: I think you can keep the shorter `l != ""`, since ReadLines won't return a `null` line.

Comment: @Evk I am not sure how it would, I am using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` which will ignore anything that is whitespace character

Comment: @Heinzi it wont return a null line, but I want to make sure I am not writing whitespace characters

Comment: I mean last line in the output will be "some line\r\n", but OP wants (as I understand) "some line"

Comment: @Evk ah, I see what you are saying now.  Without clarification from the OP I am just going to leave as is for now

Comment: @maccettura: Just saw that the original code also hat IsNullOrWhiteSpace. Then you are right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that StreamReader.ReadLine does not return the line breaks themselves, thus destroying line break information. In other words, those two input files:

```
File 1: A\r\nB\r\n
File 2: A\r\nB
```

Will yield the same input to your method. You can't determine that way whether there was a final line break or not.

If you never want a final line break, use `Write` instead of `WriteLine` and manually add a line break at the beginning of your loop in every iteration except for the first one:

```
...
    string line;
    bool first = true;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            continue;

        if (!first)
            streamWriter.WriteLine();

        streamWriter.Write(line);
        first = false;
    }
...
```

Comment: but that I don't want, efficiency is key

Comment: @Heinzi wouldnt it be better to use `File.ReadLines()`?

Comment: @maccettura: Yes, thanks. Since you already provided an improved version, I have removed that part of my answer.

Comment: @Heinzi it wasnt me, I am not sure why.  Maybe a downvote from your first version of the answer?  I evened it out for you haha